# discord bot not responding to commands

Tags: python-3.x, command, discord.py

im trying to make a discord bot and im trying to create a command for it. But the bot does not respond to the command. Here's the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('discord')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='err.log', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

token = 'BOT TOKEN'
GUILD = 'My test server'
prefix = bot.command_prefix

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds, name=GUILD)
    print(
        f'{bot.user} is connected to the following server:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
    )
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name="minecraft"))


#here is the command where the bot is not responding to
@bot.command(name='say')
async def say(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

bot.run(token)
```

any help???

Comment: Everything looks fine, are you actually running the file?

Comment: yes, here's the output:
""the bot name"" is connected to the following server:
My test server(id: 818450344492400710)

Comment: Are you sure the bot has permissions to send message in that channel? Try adding an `on_message` function that prints and sends whatever the user says

Comment: it has administrator permissions

Comment: the answer below worked, thx Aditya Tomar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `on_message` event.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('discord')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='err.log', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

token = 'BOT TOKEN'
GUILD = 'My test server'
prefix = bot.command_prefix

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds, name=GUILD)
    print(
        f'{bot.user} is connected to the following server:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
    )
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name="minecraft"))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    await bot.process_commands(message)

#here is the command where the bot is not responding to
@bot.command() # you don't need name to be say, since it's already say in the command definition
async def say(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: Why should this work? `discord.py` already implements this [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/bot.py#L946-L975)