# Discord bot isn't responding to commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I've been using the

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, 
activity=discord.Game(''))
  print('Successfully logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Hello! It's great to see you!")

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

code for commands. I expected to have it respond "Hello! It's great to see you!" when I said !hello (! = prefix). But it returned nothing. Not even an error. Does anyone know why? Also, please don't show [discord bot not responding to commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66719612/16292100) or [Discord command bot doesn't responde (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67314348/discord-command-bot-doesnt-responde-python) because I tried both, and neither worked.

Comment: I think we need the full code for helping you with that. Does your code contain `client = discord.Client()` ?

Comment: Does the code return any error ?

Comment: there isnt enough context to solve the problem. please show the full code

Comment: Sorry about that... I was offline when this was commented and then it was closed so I never responded. If your still looking at this, please go to: [Discord bot isn't responding to commands 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68144827/discord-bot-isnt-responding-to-commands-2-0).

Comment: Is that the complete code? The other examples seem to have something like `client.run` in them. And what are you sending it? (what does your command look like?)

Comment: well the complete code is very long cuz I was trying to do embeds and stuff with long image links. I guess I could send literally the whole thing if needed

Comment: Make a specialized example that includes just enough code to show your problem in action. Post that in full. See [mre]

Comment: changed. is this good?

Comment: The problem statement is still a bit vague, along the lines of "I sent A and expected B to happen" would be better. And the linked questions suggest other things to check: access, whether it can see messages from others etc.

Comment: please elaborate on: And the linked questions suggest other things to check: access, whether it can see messages from others etc. I do not quite understand what your trying to get across here

Comment: i found out that one of the functions in my WHOLE code broke it. so the code i added works. im not adding things until i break it again.

Comment: issue found! the

Answer (score 0):

I cant chat here because of lack of reputation so I answer it here instead. you should post the full code to make the job easier.

.

Cause 1:

You didn't add a prefix. You need a prefix to use the command

look onto your `client`. Did you tell the prefix already? like:

`client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "-")`

if so, add this and it should work!

.

Cause 2:

You didn't import `from discord.ext import commands`

this is important if you want to use commands, import that and it should work!

.

Cause 3:

You mixing up `client` and `bot`

this might not happen but here it goes, You might mix up `client` or `bot` on the decorator, which is `@client.command`

if you use client (like `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "-")`), use `@client.command` on the decorator, while if you use Bot (`bot = commmands.Bot(command_prefix = "-")`) then you should use `@bot.command` on the decorator.

Hope these will help :D